# Signal reference with common-mode filter on the power lines

Tags: ground, isolation, common-mode-choke, isolator

What is the recommended way to handle the following situation regarding the control signals?

Since the ground is separated with a common-mode choke between the source and the destination I'm thinking of using some kind of isolators (like the [ADuMs](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adum142e.html) from Analog Devices) for the I/O signals.

[image: Signal isolation with CMC on the power lines]

Answer (score 1):

High impedance, low bandwidth signals can be coupled directly, through a resistor, bypassed with a capacitor to ground at the far end.

Note that any impedance across the main CMC, acts in parallel to reduce its impedance and therefore attenuation.  So, all signals coupled in this way, act to reduce its peak impedance.

If higher bandwidth or lower impedance is required, then additional CMCs can be used, with at least one winding per CMC being a ground wired in parallel with the GND_PSU/GND_PCB winding.

If significant DC voltage drops across this winding, consider using a relatively large value coupling capacitor (1uF+?) to these windings, so as to avoid DC bias and thus saturation in them.  Likewise, avoid coupling power supplies of more than some ~mA, whose unbalanced currents will saturate the smaller CMC(s).

Typically, data-line chokes are best available and affordable in pairs only, so you will need to use one for each signal, and the other line for GND reference in this way.

Here is an example illustrating all the above, plus some damping that may be necessary/desirable in a real application.

[image: CMC with data lines example]

C2 + C3 has been used to implement the GND coupling capacitor, further with damping provided by R5.  These values are typical for ~10µH.  The general idea for damping an LC circuit is to set \$R = \sqrt{L/C}\$ and connect the resistor in series with a capacitor several times the capacitor to be damped.  In this case, the square root takes C2, and the parallel combination of L1-L4, and C3 is several times C2.

Again, the total parallel combination of L1-L4 and the main CMC, must have high enough impedance to achieve the filtering goals.  If main CMC must be some ~mH, you may have a hard time finding adequate value data chokes (10s mH?) so that the total combination is not too low.

The left side is entirely on one (`ISOGND`) ground plane.  The right side is on a different one (regular GND).  *There is a slot between planes, bridged by signals, in exactly and only this way.*  The grounds are thus "isolated" in this AC sense: in general, they will have different AC voltages, and are allowed to move with respect to each other, while still returning to ~zero DC difference over the long term.

In this example, CS, SCK and MOSI are coming from a host on the left side, and MISO is coming from a client on the right.  As a result, these have CMOS pin drivers on the source side, and capacitive loads (input pins) on the load side.  The CMCs have some leakage inductance, which manifests here as a series inductance or transmission line between sides.  The R+C (R1+C4, etc.) thus serves to dampen that inductance, or terminate that transmission line.

This approach will provide reasonable signal quality up to the bandwidth of the chokes; with bifilar wound type data chokes, this should be sufficient for most CMOS logic purposes, e.g. SPI up to 20 MHz or thereabouts.  Less if you need very large inductances, or can't locate bifilar/twisted pair type CMCs in such values.

Higher bandwidth signals should be routed differentially anyway (LVDS), but mind that they may need CMCs in a similar fashion as well, in case the GND-GND peak AC voltage drop exceeds the common mode range of the LVDS receivers.  This *will* require a 3+ line CMC to implement, as the pair must still flow through a properly controlled (differential) impedance -- routing the P/N pair through individual CMCs likely violates the uncoupled length spec of the diff pair (or more to the point, doubles the characteristic impedance: these parts are usually around Zo ~ 100Ω already, so using two with respect to GND, they act in series).